# Rows to Columns (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has two columns, one with the type of posting and another column with the value.

Source table:

```
+-----+-------+
|Type | Value |
+-----+-------+
|  C  | 381.22|
|  D  | 25.49 |
|  C  | 25.49 |
|  D  | 25.48 |
|  C  | 705.56|
|  D  | 80.00 |
+-----+-------+
```

I need to create a view that separates types C and D, and list their values.

I need it to look like this:

```
+------+-----+
|Credit|Debit|
+------+-----+
|381.22|25.49|
|25.49 |25.48|
|705.56|80.00|
+------+-----+
```

I tried to create two separate virtual columns with SELECTS, just to list the values for the respective types.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT [value] FROM [table] WHERE [type] IN ('D')) AS Debit,
    (SELECT [value] FROM [table] WHERE [type] IN ('C')) AS Credit
```

And the error occurs because both SELECTS return more than one result:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Also try to use the `PIVOT` statement, but still unsuccessful.

Could you give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you think Sql server will know the first two rows go together without a column to designate some kind of order to the rows.  Even if you inserted a credit, then a debit, then a credit, then a debit, there is no way to guarantee the rows will be selected in that order.  You have to have a way to associate debits and credits.

Comment: @ScottHodgin that was my question when this question was asked (then deleted and re-created I believe?). Also, what if there's no matching debit to a credit? Is it assumed that the phantom row is = 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways that you can get the final result that you want. You can use `PIVOT` or you can also use an aggregate function along with a `CASE` expression, but in order to return multiple rows for each `Type` you'll need to create a unique value that you can `GROUP BY`.

I'd recommend using a windowing function like `row_number` to first generate a unique value for each row in your table partitioned by the `TYPE`.  You'd write this similar to:

```
select 
  [Type],
  [Value],
  rn = row_number() over(partition by [Type] order by (select 1))
from yourtable;
```

This creates a unique value for each row in your table by `Type` aka `Credit or`Debit`. This is needed when you aggregate your data so you will return more than one row.

Once you've created this row number, you can convert your data into columns by using either the `PIVOT` function or `CASE` with aggregate.

```
select 
  Credit = max(case when [Type] = 'C' then [Value] end),
  Debit = max(case when [Type] = 'D' then [Value] end)
from
(
  select 
    [Type],
    [Value],
    rn = row_number() over(partition by [Type] order by (select 1))
  from yourtable
) d
group by rn;
```

Or:

```
select 
  Credit = C,
  Debit = D
from
(
  select 
    [Type],
    [Value],
    rn = row_number() over(partition by [Type] order by (select 1))
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for [Type] in (C, D)
) p;
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e8a7/2). Both of these return the result:

```
| Credit | Debit |
|--------|-------|
| 381.22 |    80 |
|  25.49 | 25.48 |
| 705.56 | 25.49 |
```

If you need the `Credit` or `Debit` data to appear specifically in certain rows, than you would need to provide some additional data to tie each `Credit` or `Debit` together. These versions just convert the rows into columns of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` with `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve this:

```
SELECT Credit, Dedit
FROM ( SELECT Value AS Credit, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS RowId
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE Type = 'C' ) AS CR
JOIN ( SELECT Value AS Dedit, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS RowId
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE Type = 'D' ) AS DE ON DE.RowId = CR.RowId;
```

Sample execution with given data:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (Type CHAR(1), Value NUMERIC(9,2));

INSERT INTO TestTable (Type, Value) VALUES
('C', 381.22),
('D', 25.49 ),
('C', 25.49 ),
('D', 25.48 ),
('C', 705.56),
('D', 80.00 );

SELECT Credit, Dedit
FROM ( SELECT Value AS Credit, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS RowId
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE Type = 'C' ) AS CR
JOIN ( SELECT Value AS Dedit, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS RowId
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE Type = 'D' ) AS DE ON DE.RowId = CR.RowId;
```

Working Demo: http://rextester.com/FBDTW83211

Output:

```
Credit  | Dedit
-----------------
381.22  | 25.49
25.49   | 25.48
705.56  | 80.00
```